# how can I set height and width of vrview iframe in percentages

Tags: html, google-vr

I am using [vrview](https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/web/vrview-web) to show a 360 image in a html file but apparently it only accepts numbers as a value as shown below:

```
var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
              image: '{}',
              is_stereo: false,
              height: 95,
              width: 100,
              default_yaw: 200
            });
```

but when I try to change width or height to % values such as 100% it doesn't work.

Is there a way to manipulate it's size according to the window size?

Answer (score 0):

it has to be written as:

```
var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview',{
  image:'{}',
  is_stereo: false,
  height: '100%',
  width: '100%',
  default_yaw: 200,
});
```

in order to get the height to cover all the web page the body and the wrapper height need to be set to 100% too.